# how to set zoom in effect in story view widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

> I want to set pinch gesture for zooming in and out in Story view
> widget. I have tried gesture detector but it won't work,it won't allow
> any other widget in it.

```
body: StoryView(
    storyItems: new List.generate(
      3,
      (index) => StoryItem.pageImage(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 7),
        url: widget.image['map${n + 1}'][index],
        controller: storycontroller,
        
      ),
    ),
    controller: storycontroller,
    onStoryShow: (s) {
      print('Story Started');
      // set();
    },
    onComplete: () {
      print('Story Completed');
      print(n);
    },
    progressPosition: ProgressPosition.top,
    repeat: false,
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your widget with Flutter's [InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) widget.